# display sqlite data on a view who to textview form

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have copy this code on internet and i want to display sqlite data in a new activity when a user click on item in recycleview under textview form.

This mainActivity:

```
package com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.ui;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.utils.Utilidades;
import com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.R;
import com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.provider.ContractParaGastos;
import com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.sync.SyncAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private AdaptadorDeGastos adapter;
private TextView emptyView;
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setToolbar();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.recycle_divider));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new AdaptadorDeGastos(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_data_empty);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    SyncAdapter.inicializarSyncAdapter(this);
}

private void setToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

public void onClickFab(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InsertActivity.class);
    if (Utilidades.materialDesign())
        startActivity(intent,
                ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());

    else startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_sync) {
        SyncAdapter.sincronizarAhora(this, false);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    emptyView.setText("Cargando datos...");
    // Consultar todos los registros
    return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            ContractParaGastos.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
    emptyView.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

and that is a Database:

```
package com.herprogramacion.crunch_expenses.provider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Clase envoltura para el gestor de Bases de datos
 */
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    createTable(database); // Crear la tabla "gasto"
}

/**
 * Crear tabla en la base de datos
 *
 * @param database Instancia de la base de datos
 */
private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String cmd = "CREATE TABLE " + ContractParaGastos.GASTO + " (" +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.MONTO + " TEXT, " +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.ETIQUETA + " TEXT, " +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.FECHA + " TEXT, " +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.DESCRIPCION + " TEXT," +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.ID_REMOTA + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.ESTADO + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "+ ContractParaGastos.ESTADO_OK+"," +
            ContractParaGastos.Columnas.PENDIENTE_INSERCION + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
    database.execSQL(cmd);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try { db.execSQL("drop table " + ContractParaGastos.GASTO); }
    catch (SQLiteException e) { }
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Somebody help me to diplay this data in a new view please!

ps:i'm a french speaking, excuse my poor english. But i work it.

Comment: You need to modify the RecyclerView.Adapter class. RecyclerView has no itemClick listener. So you need to modify the adapter for click listener.

Comment: yes i know but how to create new activity for save sqlite data.

Comment: my real problem is how to write a code who take  sqlite data and save this in new activity.

Comment: That is a very long process and requires lots of coding. 
In Google I/O 2017, Google announced new libraries to make this easy for developers. Please read the guide https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> my real problem is how to write a code who take sqlite data and save
>   this in new activity.

As you have a column defined as `name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` this column will uniquely identify the row in the table. As such, it's basically a matter of ascertaining this value and passing it to the activity that is called. A convenient way of doing this is by passing the value via an Intent Extra.

Note! in all likelihood you don't need `AUTOINCREMENT`, `name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, will still give you a unique row identifier, but without the overheads and restrictions of using [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

An Intent Extra is created using the the Intent's put method, it takes a key to identify the data/value and the data/value itself.

---

Here's an example of using Intent Extras :-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DBTableDataViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DBTableDataViewActivity.INTENTKEY_DATABASENAME,mCurrentDB.getname());
    intent.putExtra(DBTableDataViewActivity.INTENTKEY_DATABASEPATH,mCurrentDB.getPath());
    intent.putExtra(DBTableDataViewActivity.INTENTKEY_TABLENAME,tablebame);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The first line creates an `Intent` object instance, referred to as `intent`, that will be used to start the DBtableDataViewActivity (the other activity).

The next three lines add Extras to the Intent (Strings in this case for the Database name, it's path and the Table name). The first parameter of the `putExtra` method is the key, as a String, to identify the Extra. The second parameter is the value to be sent (in your case you would put a **`long`**).

The last line starts the Activity according to the Intent.

- The keys, in this case are based upon :-

  - `public static final String INTENTKEY_DATABASEPATH = "ik_dbpath";`
  - `public static final String INTENTKEY_DATABASENAME = "ik_dbname";`
  - `public static final String INTENTKEY_TABLENAME = "ik_tablename";`

In the called Activity you retrieve the Intents e.g. :-

```
    Intent callingintent = this.getIntent();
    mDatabaseName = callingintent.getStringExtra(INTENTKEY_DATABASENAME);
    mDatabasepath = callingintent.getStringExtra(INTENTKEY_DATABASEPATH);
    mTableName = callingintent.getStringExtra(INTENTKEY_TABLENAME);
```

One thing to note, as you will likely be sending a `long` is that you have to include a default value, as a second parameter, that is used if the Extra doesn't exist.

As a unique row identifier (**rowid**) should not be 0 (note you can force a rowid to be 0), then using a default value of 0 may suit.

Your solution, after you have obtained the unique row identifier (for this example into a long variable named **`id`**) would be along the lines of:-

**Invoking Activity**

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("ROWID_INTENT_KEY",id);
     startActivity(intent);
```

**NewActivity**

```
     ....
     onCreate() {
         ....
         long passed_id = this.getIntent().getLongExtra("ROWID_INTENT_KEY",0);
         if (passed_id > 0) {
             ..... do you stuff here 
         } else {
             .... handle no valid id passed
         }
     }
```

In the above you could then retrieve the other relevant data by querying the database. An alternative could be to pass the other data via additional Intent Extras.

### Here's a more Complex example:-

#### The Invoking Activity

invokes the ProductsAddEditActivity, passing multiple values via Intent Extras.

```
public void productEdit() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ProductsAddEditActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(
            StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_CALLINGACTIVITY,
            THIS_ACTIVITY
    );
    intent.putExtra(
            StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_CALLINGMODE,
            StandardAppConstants.CM_EDIT
    );
    intent.putExtra(StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_PRODUCTID,
            plcsr.getLong(
                    plcsr.getColumnIndex(PRODUCTID_COLUMN)
            ));
    intent.putExtra(StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_PRODUCTNAME,
            plcsr.getString(
                    plcsr.getColumnIndex(PRODUCTNAME_COLUMN
                    )
            ));
    intent.putExtra(StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_STORAGEID,
            plcsr.getLong(
                    plcsr.getColumnIndex(PRODUCTSTORAGEREF_COLUMN)
            ));
    intent.putExtra(StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_STORAGEORDER,
            plcsr.getInt(
                    plcsr.getColumnIndex(PRODUCTSTORAGEORDER_COLUMN)
            ));
    intent.putExtra(menucolorcode,passedmenucolorcode);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

#### in the ProductsAddeditActivity (effecctively in the onCreate method) :-

```
    caller = getIntent().getStringExtra(
            StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_CALLINGACTIVITY
    );
    calledmode = getIntent().getIntExtra(
            StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_CALLINGMODE,
            StandardAppConstants.CM_CLEAR
    );
    passedstorageid = 0;
    if (calledmode == StandardAppConstants.CM_EDIT) {
        passedproductid = getIntent().getLongExtra(
                StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_PRODUCTID,
                0
        );
        passedproductname = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_PRODUCTNAME
        );
        inputproductname.setText(passedproductname);
        passedorder = getIntent().getIntExtra(
                StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_STORAGEORDER,0
        );
        inputproductorder.setText(Integer.toString(passedorder));
        passedstorageid = getIntent().getLongExtra(
                StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_STORAGEID,0
        );
        passedstoragname = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                StandardAppConstants.INTENTKEY_STORAGENAME
        );
        inputproductfilter.setText("");
        this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.productseditlabel));
    }
    stcsr.moveToPosition(-1);
    while (stcsr.moveToNext()) {
        if (stcsr.getLong(stcsr.getColumnIndex(
                STORAGEID_COLUMN
        )) == passedstorageid) {
            inputproductstorage_spinner.setSelection(stcsr.getPosition());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok @MikeT please look my answer and help me to correct it please!